# Azure owin authorization with roles doesn' work in azure portal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, owin, azureportal

I have the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) how to configure easy `authorization` to sign-in users from my own `Azure` `active directory` tenant.
I've made only the one change in this code, I've marked HomeController by my implementation of AuthorizeAttribute as an user cannot be in my page without authentication/authorization.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The `authorization` configuration is listed below.

```
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    { 
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This code works well on my local machine (I change PostLogoutRedirectUri config param on https://localhost:port to work locally). I'm able to get `Azure Active Directory` user data and make attribute filtering by Admin `role`. Also, methods like IsInRole works good as well.
But when I deploy this code to Azure Portal, I see the following error in browser : *You do not have permission to view this directory or page.*.

When I open a portal log stream, I see the markup of 403 error page with this text : **HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden**.

My portal configuration is below:

1. In list of App Services, I have my application with name:WebApp-OpenIDConnect.
2. In Access control (IAM) - I see my user which have `Owner` role.
3. I've configured authentication/authorization section with turning on App Service Authentication. Also, I set *Log in with Azure Active Directory* value in *Action to take when request is not authenticated* settings as well as I've configured Azure Active Directory with creating a new Azure Add App.
4. I already have `Azure active directory` group with name '**Admin**'. I see on overview page, that my user is member of this group.
5. I've added roles description in the app registration manifest as below.

   ```
    "appRoles": [
    {
    "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
    "displayName": "Admin",
    "id": "637b0b37-####-####-####-############",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "Admin description",
    "value": "Admin"      
    }]
   ```
6. In `Azure Active Directory`/`Enterprise applications`/`User and groups`, I've added my user and assigned Admin role for him.
7. I've checked that ClientId from my app.config has the same guid as Application ID in the app registration page.
8. The `Kudu` (`App services`/`Advanced tools`) shows me the following app settings:

   - WEBSITE_AUTH_DEFAULT_PROVIDER  "AzureActiveDirectory"

**UPDATE:** If I remove Roles="Admin" parameter from attribute (leave only Authorize()), authorization works correctly and even claims collection contains *Admin* role value in `roles` claim. But when I return Roles parameter back, 403 error appears again.

**UPDATE2:** I think the problem is related with differences in claim role types. When I run my application locally. I have the claim type name with namespace and in single form : **http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role** (the value is *Admin*), but when I run my application in azure portal, I see claim type name in plural form and without namespace : **roles** (the value is *Admin* as well as previous).

**UPDATE3** I've tried to update **RoleClaimType** name in my configuration section as presented below trying to change the mismatching between role claim type in claims collection and expected RoleClaimType in `ClaimsIdentity` object:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    { 
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                }
            });
```

but after deployment my application to azure, the type of claim still has old value : **RoleClaimType = http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role** and wasn't changed by my configuration changes. When I run localy - type name is changed.

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Can you share the fiddler trace of your auth flow captured for both localhost and azure deployed instance?

Comment: You can inspect the access_token in both localhost and azure deployed scnarios (use jwt.ms) and make sure that the role claim is named http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role in both cases.